# Xcode: create app that passes MacOS quarantine without payment?

Tags: xcode, macos, code-signing

I've created a MacOS app in Xcode, with a 'Personal Team' based on my AppleID, and set Xcode to Automatically Manage Signing.

However, it appears that the app still fails to pass quarantine when installed on any new Mac.

The source code and binary ca be found here:
https://github.com/benwiggy/APPlayMIDI

Is it actually possible to make an app that passes quarantine without paying Apple's developer subscription; and if not, is there any purpose in my code-signing through my AppleID?

I've posted on Apple's dev forums without answer.

Comment: Why the downvotes - is this offtopic or unreasonable? Where else to ask this, if not here?

Comment: So now the question is changed to what is code signing? https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The developer program, which is not free, allows you to be an Identified Developer who can notarize apps to be allowed thru the gatekeeper.
As far as the fee goes, I pay more for my car tags every year; it is a good value.

Comment: So what is the point of Xcode allowing me to sign my app with my AppleID  when I'm not an 'identified developer'?

Comment: When you are a one-man-shop there is no point.  An employee of a major corporation may never have access to Apple deployment certificates for their development, unless they are the deployment engineer, therefor Xcode allows various certification levels for the needs of development groups.